# Force nodemon to watch file from node_modules

Tags: nodemon

Hello is there any chance of making `nodemon` watch for changes of a specific module in `node_modules`

I have started the nodemon like this

```
nodemon index.js --watch 'node_modules/specific_module/**
```

I have also tried with `nodemon.json` file

```
"watch": [
  "node_modules/specific_module/**"
]
```

But to no avail. Is there any way of achieving this behavior or anything in `node_modules` is forever ignored no matter what i do?

Comment: Check the docs on github: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/faq.md#overriding-the-underlying-default-ignore-rules

Comment: Yeah I have just found that not sure how I failed to notice that. Well make it an answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Nodemon: watch the modules folder

As @variable mentions in the comments, here is a `nodemon.json` to include `node_modules` (and obviously exclude `.git`:

```
{
"ignoreRoot": [".git"]
}
```

From the [docs](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/faq.md#overriding-the-underlying-default-ignore-rules):

> Say you did want to watch the node_modules directory. You have to override the ignoreRoot. If you wanted this on a per project basis, add the config to you local nodemon.json. If you want it for all projects, add it to $HOME/nodemon.json: